# JMeter SummaryReport AggregateReport is recording the results from View Results in Table data

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 listeners setup to write to a file SummaryReport, AggregateReport, and ViewResultsInTable.  I am on a MacBook os Big Sur 11.5.2 and JMeter 5.4.1.  Weirdly enough, I get the ViewResultsInTable data in both the SummaryReport.csv and AggregateReport.csv.  While I am writing the Test Plan, it is easy to recover because the UI Reports are correct.  However, when I want to move to the real test and run it from the command line, I won't be able to recover.

Is there any way to clear that up?

Answer (score 0):

Saving and reading the test results are generic in all [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners). Hence you will get identical test results in all the files.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you didn't click "Configure" button and changed the metrics to store you will get the same files no matter which listener(s) you use, you just ended up with 3 identical files (plus the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) if you're [running your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui))
2. In case of Summary Report and Aggregate Report listeners all the metrics you're seeing are **calculated** from the individual Sample Result entries so if you open the .jtl results file after your non-GUI test execution finishes you will see the calculated aggregate metrics.
3. In general you should be using Listeners only for tests development and, it doesn't make a lot of sense to add Listeners for the test execution, [they don't add any value, just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing). So disable/remove all the listeners, you should be able to get all you need from the aforementioned .jtl results file.
4. If you want to see the output of Aggregate Report and/or Summary Report listeners without opening JMeter GUI - you can generate them from the .jtl results file using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/)